# Outlook Add-In Crashes on long sync operations

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I'm new in Microsoft Add-in development. I'm loading site in iframe through the Add-In, and this site has a big settings data. So when I'm trying to write this data to store add-in crashes.

I'm using windows 10 ver 1909, outlook build 16.0.13503.20418

[Add-In error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a83TR.jpg)

Comment: Could you add a code sample that reproduces the issue? Does the add-in load first and then show an error, or does it never load?

Comment: This error could also be due to governance control as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/privacy-and-security#end-users-privacy-and-performance-concerns. Outlook rich clients monitor the performance of installed Outlook add-ins and may disable those Outlook add-ins that exceed certain limits.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't add a code sample, because it is big application. Add-In is loading, in my add-in i'm using iframe with my app. And on big sync operation such as uploading files or using react store - add-in crashes. When I have tried to reduce the data, it was help, but what the limit of data which uses browser inside outlook desktop (the issue is not reproducing on old versions outlook desktop where add-in runs through IE 11)

Comment: The add-in could be hitting resource usage limits if it is uploading large amounts of data. Outlook rich clients do monitor resource usage. More information about the limits that are enforced is documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization

Comment: But why it works pretty for Office on MAC OS. They are using Safari into the outlook app. Why edge (inner outlook add-in) can't work as well